# Detecting Multiple Lines in 2D Point Data using RANSAC

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression, cluster-analysis

I have datasets of points plotted on an XY axis, and in each dataset, I know in advance the number of lines that the points should form. My goal is to detect these lines using a method like RANSAC. In the provided example, I know there should be 2 lines.

Here’s a visual representation of one such dataset:

[image: example plot]

I’m having difficulty configuring RANSAC (or another method) to consistently detect the correct number of lines, especially when the lines are close to each other or have varying densities of points.

Is there a way to guide RANSAC (or suggest another method) to detect the exact number of lines I know in advance for each dataset?

What I’ve tried:

1. Applied RANSAC using scikit-learn.
2. Adjusted the threshold and other parameters, but still not getting consistent results across different datasets.

Example for my expectations:

[image: Example of expected detection]

Comment: Sounds like a difficult problem!  In the general case I'm not sure it's possible to always reliably recover every line.  For example, with just two parallel lines, if they were placed closer than their standard error then I don't see how you'd ever reliably distinguish between them.  Question might be better suited to https://stats.stackexchange.com/ especially given the lack of code you've included as this site is about fixing code.

Answer (score 0):

Let's create some dataset:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import HDBSCAN
from sklearn.linear_model import RANSACRegressor

np.random.seed(12345)

def dataset(n=3, m=10, slope=(2, 3), intercept=(4, 7), sigma=0.1):
    x = np.linspace(0, 1, m)
    a = np.linspace(*slope, n)
    b = np.linspace(*intercept, n)
    xs = []
    ys = []
    for i in range(n):
        xs.extend(x)
        ys.extend(a[i] * x + b[i] + sigma * np.random.normal(size=x.size))
    X = np.stack([np.array(xs), np.array(ys)]).T
    return X

n = 3
X = dataset(n=n)
```

First operation, we need to cluster points:

```
cluster = HDBSCAN(min_cluster_size=5, min_samples=3, cluster_selection_epsilon=0.15)
cluster.fit(X)
# array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2, -1])
```

Clustering is not perfect and might be tuned with respect to your datasets and/or refined in post-processing.

Once clustering is done, we can perform RANSAC on each cluster:

```
errors = []
fig, axe = plt.subplots()
for i in range(n):
    q = cluster.labels_ == i
    x = X[q, 0].reshape(-1, 1)
    y = X[q, 1]
    regressor = RANSACRegressor()
    regressor.fit(x, y)
    errors.append(X[:, 1] - regressor.predict(X[:,0].reshape(-1, 1)))
    axe.scatter(x, y, marker="o")
    axe.plot(x, regressor.predict(x))
axe.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], marker="x", color="black")
axe.grid()
E = np.array(errors).T
```

[image]

Then if you need to refine clustering, you can use errors E (vertical distance of points to each line) to post-process clusters and perform RANSAC again on corrected clusters.

```
cluster2 = HDBSCAN(min_cluster_size=5, min_samples=3, cluster_selection_epsilon=0.15)
cluster2.fit(E)
# array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
```

[image]