# How to exclude abnormal data points and smooth the data before linear fitting

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I want to calculate the modulus by linear fitting of the strain-stress curve. However, since the pressure data obtained scatters a lot, sometimes the fitting results are not good.
I think two things can improve the situation. First, some extremely large or small values need to be ignored, Second, maybe the data of pressure can be processed in some way before the fitting. For example, maybe a smooth or running average could help.

The following is the Python code I used for linear fitting.

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from pathlib import Path
import os


def f(x, a, b):
   return a + b * x

def get_modulus(BoxValue, PressureValue, strain_cutoff = 0.012):
   strain_all = np.array(BoxValue / BoxValue[0] - 1)
   stress_all = np.array(- PressureValue / 10000)
   strain = strain_all[strain_all <= strain_cutoff]
   stress = stress_all[strain_all <= strain_cutoff]
   popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, strain, stress)
   # modulus = popt[1]
   # modulus_std_dev = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))[1]
   return popt[1], np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))[1]

BoxValue = np.loadtxt("box-xx_0water_150peg.dat"))[:,1]
PressureValue = np.loadtxt(f"pres-xx_0water_150peg"))[:,1]
modulus, modulus_std = get_modulus(BoxValue, PressureValue)
```

Two sets of data can be downloaded here.

The first one: [box data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CpLrZ3GZ-5F3tJyW2CiG1opN3PzIBdEr/view?usp=sharing), and [pressure data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13CmRdNYtXbLRxuTlXcUSy0_qbgPoXxyV/view?usp=sharing)

The second one: [box data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-t_jo88ZBxuaqPCNiMy8Bnsboyz9DiCb/view?usp=sharing), and [pressure data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12O0JtdeNcYQMFauPoQFUk2_V4vpQSV4K/view?usp=sharing)

The pressure data of the second one has an abnormal point on the 180th line, which I think should be excluded from the fitting.

Could you please tell me what is the best practice to do this and provide the code as well?

Any suggestions or comments are welcome.

Comment: The problem as you describe it is exactly what RANSAC is for: excluding data before fitting. You should have a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

### TL; DR

Your dataset at too far away from linearity to be handled uniquely by Robust Regression. You definitely needs dataset pre-processing before being able to regress modulus.

### Robust regression

First we process your data:

```
def prepare(suffix):
    # Load:
    x = pd.read_csv("box" + suffix, sep="\t", header=None, names=["id", "x"])
    y = pd.read_csv("pres" + suffix, sep="\t", header=None, names=["id", "y"])
    # Merge:
    data = x.merge(y, on=["id"])
    # Post process:
    data["strain"] = data["x"] / data["x"][0] - 1.
    data["stress"] = - data["y"] / 10_000.
    return data
```

Then we perform Robust Linear Regression on it:

```
def analyse(data):
    # Regress:
    X, y = data["strain"].values.reshape(-1, 1), data["stress"].values
    regressor = TheilSenRegressor()
    regressor.fit(X, y)
    # Predict:
    yhat = regressor.predict(X)
    score = r2_score(y, yhat)
    # Render:
    fig, axe = plt.subplots()
    axe.scatter(X, y)
    axe.plot(X, yhat, color="orange")
    axe.set_title("Regression")
    axe.set_xlabel("Strain")
    axe.set_ylabel("Stress")
    axe.grid()
    return {
        "slope": regressor.coef_,
        "intercept": regressor.intercept_,
        "score": score,
        "axe": axe
    }
```

First dataset returns (probably not linear at all):

```
df1 = prepare("-xx_0water_150peg.dat")
sol1 = analyse(df1)
#{'slope': array([2.22561879]),
# 'intercept': 0.025513888992521497,
# 'score': 0.7902902090920214,
# 'axe': <AxesSubplot:title={'center':'Regression'}, xlabel='Strain', ylabel='Stress'>}
```

[image]

Second dataset returns (multiple setup):

```
df2 = prepare("-yy_200water_150peg.dat")
sol2 = analyse(df2)
#{'slope': array([29.5666213]),
# 'intercept': 0.0008528267952350494,
# 'score': 0.007683701094953643,
# 'axe': <AxesSubplot:title={'center':'Regression'}, xlabel='Strain', ylabel='Stress'>}
```

Where the strong outlier does not affect the regression:

[image]

But if we zoom, we detect at least two different behaviours:

[image]

### Conclusions

- Robust regression will help you to filter out few strong outliers without having the need to handle them manually
- Your dataset are non linear in some extent:

  - First dataset exhibits a negative curvature
  - Second dataset contains at least two behaviours that need to be split before analysis or if you wish to automatize it add [clustering before fitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77349990/detecting-multiple-lines-in-2d-point-data-using-ransac/77547408#77547408)
- You need to address if intercept must be fitted, generally strain-stress curves pass by the origin (no strain, no stress).

Comment: Hello, thank you very much! I used a cutoff for the strain values, the curve is in a small strain range, in this case, expect the strong outliers, I did not find data has two very different regions. But thanks for pointing it out. Could you please tell me why you use TheilSenRegressor? I used RANSAC as suggested in the comment. Could you please tell me which one is better for my data?

Comment: @FreeAir The description of it seems to show that it is almost, roughly, the same thing. I say "almost", because, RANSAC chooses randomly subsamples on which regression works well, and does that until it finds a good subsample. While, in theory, this one comprehensively tries all possible subsamples and keep the best. So, in theory, this one is deterministic while RANSAC needs some luck. But the description also says that if the number of possible subsamples is too large, then, subsamples are chosen randomly.

Comment: And number of subsamples are always too large, obtiously. It is (as stated in documentation, and as it is logical, a "n choose p" number. Which is always huge, unless you really want to choose only 1 or 2 samples, or, on the contrary, all but one or 2.  So, it is the same. (Well RANSAC has a refining strategy, trying to add firstly excluded samples to the data if they fit well the model, and then refining the model. But in your case, with very few outliers, it wouldn't change a lot).

Comment: Another difference is that RANSAC is, in theory again, not restricted to linear regression. Any regression can use ransac (you just have to wrap the regression inside a "choose a subsample, perform regression, add to the data the excluded data that fit well the fitted regression, refine regression with those ; restart all that 100 times, keep the one that fit the more data" loop). But I say "in theory" there again, because in practice, existing code for RANSAC are for linear regression.

Comment: So, long story short, it doesn't really matter which one you choose. Both have the same advantage: they can perform linear regression on randomly chosen subsamples until they find a subsample with a good linear model (rest being then outliers). And both have the same inconvenient: your data needs to abide the model (here linear) that you've postulated they abide to. If it is not really linear, then, neither ransac, nor theilsen would work correctly (that is a given for any model anyway: choosing a model family is an asumption, always only partly true, that your data fit)